# Delete the last occurence of an increment

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, function

I would like know how I can delete the last occurrence of an increment in a print. I show you an example:

```py
 copi = copy(pa[0])
 for i in copi:
      print(i,"+", end=''),
 print("=", sum(copi))
```

And my result is :

```
2 +3 +4 +5 +6 += 20
```

But like you see, the problem is that I have a "+" too much.

Can you help to have this result :

```
2 +3 +4 +5 +6 = 20
```

Thanks for reading me !

Comment: May be better to  intiate an empty string to feed  it in your loop and eventually remove last caracter before printing?

Comment: `2 +3 +4 +5 +6 = 20` why is it `15`? shouldn't it be `20`?

Comment: yes sry I missclicked

Comment: Please use print(' + '.join([str(i+1) for i in copi]), end='')

Comment: Strings have a powerful [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method. Remove the `for` loop and use `print(' + '.join(str(value) for value in copi), end='')` (or `value + 1` if you really want that). If you don't need the increment you could go to the next level: `print(' + '.join(map(str, copi)), end='')`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways. Easiest is to omit the last item from the loop and use it afterwards (although this doesn't work with generators).

```py
copi = copy(pa[0])
for i in copi[:-1]:
    print(i+1,"+", end='')
print(copi[-1]+1, "=", sum(copi))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `str.join` and drop the `for` loop:

```
' + '.join(map(str, copi))
```

ex:

```
copi = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(' + '.join(map(str, copi)), '=', sum(copi))
```

output:

```
2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'+'.join` here.

```
copi=[2,3,4,5,6]
print(f'{"+".join(map(str,copi))}={sum(copi)}')
```